# How to change Linux kerner parameters in Azure Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, yaml, azure-aks

I have an Azure Kubernetes Cluster with 4 nodes (Linux boxes). I provisioned the AKS cluster using yaml manifests. I want to update the following kernel parameters: net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30, net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65500. The yaml manifest is below. How to update the yaml to include the kernel parameters that I have to change?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jmeter-slaves
  labels:
    jmeter_mode: slave
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      jmeter_mode: slave
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        jmeter_mode: slave
    spec:
      securityContext:
        sysctls:
        - name: net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
          value: "1024 65500"
      containers:
      - name: jmslave
        image: prabhaharanv/jmeter-slave:latest
        command: ["/jmeter/apache-jmeter-$(JMETERVERSION)/bin/jmeter-server"]
        args: ["-Dserver.rmi.ssl.keystore.file /jmeter/apache-jmeter-$(JMETERVERSION)/bin/rmi_keystore.jks","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(MY_POD_IP)", "-Dserver.rmi.localport=50000", "-Dserver_port=1099"]
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
          requests:
            cpu: "0.5"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1099
        - containerPort: 50000
        env:
          - name: MY_POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: JMETERVERSION
            value: "5.1.1"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jmeter-slaves-svc
  labels:
    jmeter_mode: slave
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 1099
      name: first
      targetPort: 1099
    - port: 50000
      name: second
      targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    jmeter_mode: slave

---
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/) official kubernetes documentation section. There is all the information you need to set the mentioned **kernel parameters** or using different terminology - **sysctls**, in your `Pod`.

Note that there are so called **safe** and **unsafe** sysctls.

As to setting `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65500`, it is considered as *safe one* and you can set it for your `Pod` using a `securityContext` like below without a need to reconfigure the **kubelet** on your node:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sysctl-example
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
      value: "1024 65500"
    - name: net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
      value: "30"
  ...
```

However if you try to set this way also `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` you'll see plenty of failed attempts to create a `Pod` with the status `SysctlForbidden`:

```
kubectl get pods
...
nginx-deployment-668d699fd8-zlvdm   0/1     SysctlForbidden   0          31s
nginx-deployment-668d699fd8-ztzpr   0/1     SysctlForbidden   0          58s
nginx-deployment-668d699fd8-zx4vq   0/1     SysctlForbidden   0          24s
...
```

It happens because `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` is an *unsafe sysctl* which needs to be explicitely allowed on node level by reconfiguring your **kubelet**.

To allow it you need to edit your **kubelet** configuration, specifically add one more option to those with which it is already started. You will typically find those options in file `/etc/default/kubelet`. You simply need to add one more:

```
--allowed-unsafe-sysctls 'net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout'
```

and restart your **kubelet**:

```
systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

Once `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` is allowed on node level, you can set it the same way as any *safe sysctls* i.e. via `securityContext` in your `Pod` specification.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I included this snippet in the above file but I received the following error. Do you know why this is thrown?

error: error validating "jmeter_master_deploy.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec): missing required field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Note that `SecurityCotext` must be at the same indentation level as `containers` they are both part of `spec` section. It looks like in your current yaml `containers` are not under `spec`. If you still have some difficulties in correcting it, please post your edited `yaml` in your question and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I just made some changes to my yaml and the question is updated with the changes. I opened a shell session to one of the pod on Kubernetes dashboard to allow the unsafe sysctl but I could not find kubelet file in /etc/default/.

Comment: Because you're supposed to configure it on your `nodes`, not in `Pod`. That's why *unsafe* sysctls are called *unsafe* - enabling them may affect stability of your nodes and in consequence the whole cluster. But if you need them for some reason and you know what you're doing there is a way to allow them. There is one impornant caveat however, when it comes to managed kubernetes solutions such as **azure-aks**. I'm not very familiar with the **Azure** platform but e.g. on **GKE** by default you have **auto-upgrade** and **auto-repair** features enabled, which may overwrite your changes.

Comment: I am able to successfully verify that net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range is changed as per the yaml file. But is there any other way to communicate to the AKS node to set the unsafe sysctl except the steps given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way than ssh-ing into your AKS node. You need it because you need to change your kubelets configuration, which are deployed on each node. Good to hear that you successfully managed to change `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`. If you need to change also `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`, remember to include it in `securityContext` of your `Pod` specification, after you successfully enable it in `kubelet/s` configuration. Keep in mind that change should be applied separately on each node. When it comes to kubelet custom configuration on AKS it doesnt seem so easy.

Comment: As you can read [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/686) ore [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/323) there still isn't a straightforward solution available. You can change your **kubelet** configuration directly on your AKS nodes but you have no guarantee that your changes won't be overwritten in future.

Comment: Thanks @mario. This really helps

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If the answer was helpful you may consider marking it as an accepted answer and/or upvote it (at least 15 points of reputation required). Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) article in Help Center.